# How is Weiss mean field approximation actually maximising the partition function of Boltzmann's distribution?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, mean-field-theory, boltzmann-equation

Considering other mean field approximation (e.g. Max entropy approach or $<S_i> = m_i
+\delta S_i$ , $\delta S_i \simeq0$), a common approach that I've seen is that of maximising the partition function $Z$ of the Boltzmann Distribution $\frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta E(S)}$.

Going into the Weiss Mean Field Approximation, starting from an Hamiltonian $E(S) = -J\sum_{(i,j)}S_iS_j-\mu B\sum_iS_i$ we obtain that $<S_i> = <\tanh(BJ\sum_{j \neq i}S_j + \beta\mu B)>$ and then we proceed onto the step of $<S_i> = \tanh(BJ\sum_{j \neq i}<S_j> + \beta\mu B)$.

In all the other approaches it is clear to se that we're maximising the partition function $Z$ to get $<S_i>$.

How is it the case here?

Comment: Seems almost the answer: https://scipost.org/10.21468/SciPostPhysLectNotes.35

Answer (score 0):

For mean field theory the key concept is free energy.

For conditions of constant volume and temperature the free energy is the Helmholtz function $F = U - TS$, satisfying $dF = - S dT - p dV$ for a closed simple compressible system. The key idea is that the equilibrium state is the one of *minimum free energy*.

In statistical mechanics (canonical ensemble) we have
$$
F = - kT \ln Z
$$
so if $T$ is fixed then $F$ takes a minimum value when $Z$ takes a maximum value.

Note also that in the discussion of mean field theory one is often using the above result both for equilibrium states and for a certain set of non-equilibrium states. You must therefore check that any expressions you employ are indeed valid for those non-equilibrium states.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer which is kind of clarifying.
Could you please point out in which step of the Weiss Mean Field approximation are we minimising the free energy (hence maximising the partition function)?